# Use of DataTemplate

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datatemplate

I'm quite new to C# and Windows Phone 7 for that sake, but none the less, I've thrown myself into trying to make a small app for myself. Here's my problem:

I'm trying to set up a DataTemplate that will position my Name and Drinks variables that I've declared in MainPage.xaml.cs. Here's my action when button1 is clicked:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string Name = participantName.Text;
        int Drinks = 0;

        listBox1.Items.Add(Name + Drinks);
    }
```

And here is my DataTemplate from MainPage.xaml

```
            <ListBox Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="7,74,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="132">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="35" />
                        <StackPanel Width="370">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Drinks}" FontSize="35" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

The problem is that my data is not shown. It works perfectly without the DataTemplate, but as soon as I use it, my text simply doesn't get through. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure if it compiles or not but I think you need to write listBox1.Items.Add(new { Name = Name , Drinks = Drinks}); so give it a try. If it works then you don't have to mess up your codes with defining an extra class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template itself is ok. The *bindings* on the template, though, are currently incorrect.

When you add a new item to the list box, you are just adding a plain old string (which is currently missing a space, BTW.) Your bindings, though, expect the object in the list to have a `Name` property and a `Drinks` property, which of course the `string` class does not have.

The usual solution here is to logically separate your data model from your presentation, by creating a class to store the data itself (probably `PersonDrink`, with the appropriate `Name` and `Drinks` properties) and then adding those objects to the list.

You should read up on the MVVM pattern, as it provides an excellent way to ensure that changes in your data are reflected in your view, and visa versa.

Comment: I forgot to add that I have a TextBox called participantName and that this is the place where I get my text from. Is it still done wrong then?

(admitted, I haven't managed to read the MVVM yet, but will do now)

Comment: @Viktor I saw that in the first code-snippet. That would only affect how you actually populate your data objects, though. They'd still be bound to your list box (and therefore to the data template) in the same way.

Comment: So how would my class look like? Something like this: `public class PersonDrink
        {
            string Name = participantName.Text;
            int Drinks = 0;
        }`

Comment: Your class would just be `public class PersonDrink { public string Name {get;set;} public int Drinks {get;set;} }`. Then adding a new person is `listBox1.Add(new PersonDrink { Name = participantName.Text, Drinks = 0 });` Again, I would encourage you to read up on MVVM and try to implement a basic version of it. It really makes WPF programming a lot easier

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm looking into the MVVM on MSDN now :)

Answer (score 0):

http://amarchandra.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/binding-multiple-object-in-wp7-using-listbox/

Here is a sample for binding data using a datatemplate. I hope this might help you.